# How do I list everything in the template cache?

Tags: angularjs

I'm having trouble figuring out what's in my template cache.  When I google, all I find is this: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache  I'm looking for documentation on all the methods available for that but can't find it.  But really all I want to know is how to list all the keys in the templateCache.  How is that done?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? It sounds like an XY problem to me.

Comment: I'm really surprised that this isn't easier. Even in `.info()` they could put a list of the keys. At least then I can see what keys the ng-html2js preprocessor is using.

Answer (score 11):

I think you can use `$provide.decorator` to wrap the `put` method and keep a list of the keys in the cache as they are added. You can then use the same idea to also add a new method to the cache factory that returns said list.

You can see an example implementation here, should be quite easy to adapt it to your needs:
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/3760#issuecomment-130343142 (pasted here for reference).

```
app.config(['$provide', function($provide) {

    // monkey-patches $templateCache to have a keys() method
    $provide.decorator('$templateCache', [
        '$delegate', function($delegate) {

            var keys = [], origPut = $delegate.put;

            $delegate.put = function(key, value) {
                origPut(key, value);
                keys.push(key);
            };

            // we would need cache.peek() to get all keys from $templateCache, but this features was never
            // integrated into Angular: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/3760
            // please note: this is not feature complete, removing templates is NOT considered
            $delegate.getKeys = function() {
                return keys;
            };

            return $delegate;
        }
    ]);
}]);
```

Comment: Thx for the example. Here is an implementation of this (with tests) in CoffeeScript

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/3760#issuecomment-226178124

Answer (score 0):

From the Angular Docs, [$templateCache](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache) is created by [$cacheFactory](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$cacheFactory) which instantiates objects of type [Cache](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$cacheFactory.Cache).

It appears there is no way to directly view everything that is in the template cache without knowing all the specific keys. You can call `.info()` on the template cache however to get the size of the template cache if that is of any help to you.

Thinkster also has a pretty sweet tutorial on the subject [here](https://thinkster.io/templatecache-tutorial/).

Answer (score 0):

I just had this prob and found a way to do this using two chrome inspector hacks:

- Setup a debug breakpoint
- using heap snapshot

see screenshots at https://github.com/DinisCruz/Book_Practical_AngularJS/issues/22#issuecomment-226160366

This is not what I really wanted (which was to access to programatically inside an Unit Test), but it helped me to debug the issue